# Compute mass function of $U=X+2Y$

Tags: probability

Let be $X$ and $Y$ random variables and let be the joint density $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{xy}{96}I_{R}(x,y)$
where $R:=\{(x,y):0<x<4,1<y<5\}$. Let be $U:=X+2Y$, its distribution function is
$$F_U(u)=P(U\leq u) = \int\int_{\{(x,y):x+2y\leq u\}} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \,dx\,dy =$$
$$\int\int_{\{(x,y):x+2y\leq u\}} cxyI_R(x,y) \,dx\,dy =\int\int_{\{(x,y):x+2y\leq u\}\cap R} cxy \,dx\,dy$$
If we draw $\{(x,y):x+2y\leq u\}\cap R$ we can see we have to consider several cases.

One case is $2<u<6$.
$$F_U(u) = \int\int_{\{(x,y):x+2y\leq u\}\cap R} cxy \,dx\,dy = \int_0^{u-2} \int_1^{\frac{u-x}{2}} cxy \, dx \, dy$$
Second case is $6<u<10$, in this case i think the integral is
$$\int_0^4\int_1^{\frac{u-4}{2}}cxy \, dy\,dx + \int_0^4\int_{{\frac{u-4}{2}}}^{\frac{u-x}{2}}cxy\,dy\,dx = u^2/96 -u/18 +1/24$$
But the solution is $(3u-8)/144$. I dont know why my second integral is bad defined.

Comment: 'Mass' should be replaced by 'density'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to derivate your result?

To be more precise, in the support $u \in [6;10)$ the integral is the following

$$F_U(u)=F_U(6)+\int_0^4 \int_{\frac{6-x}{2}}^{\frac{u-x}{2}}f(x,y)dxdy=...=F_U(6)+\frac{3u^2-16u-12}{288}$$

Thus the density, simply by derivating F, is

$$f_U(u)=\frac{3u-8}{144}$$

as stated.